# Postman if/else condition not working properly

Tags: postman-testcase

This code is not working as expected when running collection and used as a test script on the first request:

1. when console.log gives output null, the collection doesn't stop, when it should.
2. function never goes to the 'else' condition, even when I force it by changing the GET results.

   ```
    pm.test("Any?", function () {
    var jsonData = pm.response.json();
    if (pm.expect(jsonData.metadata.total_data).to.eql(0))
    {console.log('null');
    postman.setNextRequest(null);}
    else
    {console.log('Next request');
    postman.setNextRequest('Name of Next request');}
    });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use a forEach  and store the jsonData you want to check in a data array.

```
let checkingValues= [4,1,5,6,2];
checkingValues.forEach(() => {
```